# The -ls command listing weird command in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

Lady and Gentlemen,

When I want to list out something inside the directory, I do this command `ls`
Then I got the following weird command:

```
root@venus:~# ls
udo journalctl -u postgresql
```

[The screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsNbE.png)

What is the meaning of the output? Can anyone explain? My expectation is that, it should list out all directories inside the home directory but instead I got that weird command.

Thank you!

Comment: That is probably a file called `udo journalctl-u Postgres`.  Typo’s in scripts and commands frequently result in the creation of files with odd names. Don’t attribute to malice what can quite easily be explained by stupidity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very happy reading your answer. Stupidity is what makes people great in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could such a thing happen?

```
root@venus:~# ls
udo journalctl -u postgresql
```

This looks like a single file, named `udo journalctl -u postgresql`.

My guess is that you will find the content of this file is either `s` or empty.

```
root@venus:~# cat udo\ journalctl\ -u\ postgresql
```

And that this was caused by some permutation of `s>udo` rather than `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `pwd` and `ls -la` when file was created. Check contents of the file. It looks like file created by script but also check the directory path and contents before removing such file.